# Table of all users registered in the last X days

Tags: ksqldb

I have a topic derived from a MySQL users table and now want to create a table in ksqldb that always contains all users registered within the last 50 days. After spending some time in the docs I still can't find a solution for this. Windowing doesn't seem to work because it only applies to stream-stream joins as far as I can see. Is this sort of thing even possible using purely ksql, or do I need to look for other solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is currently possible with ksqlDB.  This because a filter, such as `WHERE DATEDIFF('days', user.registerDate, now()) < 50` would only be evaluated at the time the source row was received.

This isn't too different to standard SQL dbs, where a materialized view built with a similar filter would also not update automagically as time advanced.

You could likely build a system using Kafka Streams that could use *punctuation* to evict old entries.

Some enhancement requests on ksqlDB may also be of use:

- [Table over topic with time based retention](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/6313)
- [View updates](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/6314)